# Swift UI Test obtain UIApplicationMain in test

Tags: ios, swift, automated-tests

We are using Swift 3 and are attempting to write swift UI tests. We have the app building in the simulator via

```
XCUIApplication().launch()
```

We want to simulate some initial user input (a barcode scan). In order to do this we simply want to pass in the barcode to our barcodeDelegate. The barcode scanner is attached via a bluetooth.

Our definition for our UIApplicationMain is as follows

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
let bluetoothConnection = BluetoothConnection()...}
```

However, when running our tests, this line fails as unable to cast

```
let appdel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
```

The delegate is really a Optional< UIApplicationDelegate >

Attempts to cast result in

```
error: <EXPR>:3:35: error: 'AppDelegate' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context
UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

Is anyone familiar enough with how we can get our BluetoothConnection object so we can proceed with testing? Thanks!